# JavaScript error in Firefox only: Permission denied to access property "toJSON"

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api

In Google picker on the file selection, I am converting the token into JSON Like this:

```
access_token = JSON.stringify(token);
```

It is giving an error in Firefox

> Permission denied to access property "toJSON"

The same code is working fine in Chrome and IE11.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you're trying to stringify the data returned by the authorize request - *gapi.auth.authorize()*. The response object includes a reference to window and causes a circular reference error on Firefox. Chrome allows these kind of references to be stringified, while FF doesn't. 
If my guess is correct and you need the object stringified, remove the *g-oauth-window* property from the response object and you will be able to stringify it in FF.